Is there a standard name for a language $L$ of the form $L = L_1 \cdots L_n$ with $L_i \subseteq \Sigma$?
Classically, a language $L$ is defined as a (possibly finite) subset of $\Sigma^\ast$. I wondered whether the finite language formed by the concatenation of subset of $\Sigma$; that is, $L = L_1 \cdots L_n$ with $L_i \subseteq \Sigma$, would have a standard name somewhere ?
Note that all words of $L$ are of length $n$ by this definition.
As an example, with $n=2$, say $L_1 = \lbrace a,b\rbrace$ and $L_2 = \lbrace a\rbrace $, so that $L = L_1 \cdot L_2$ effectively describes the language $\lbrace aa, ba\rbrace$.

I don't understand your question. A Cartesian product of subsets of $\Sigma$ is not a subset of $\Sigma^*$, but a subset of $\Sigma \times  \dotsm \times \Sigma$.

If I understand what you mean correctly, $L$ is a subset of $\Sigma^n$, so is a finite language. As $\Sigma^$ is a graded monoid by the monoid homomorphism given by the lenght of a word, $L$ is made by elements of $\Sigma^$ of degree $n$, so you can say that $L$ is a finite language of constant degree $n$.

You are confusing the Cartesian product $\Sigma \times \dotsm \times \Sigma$ with $\Sigma^n$, the concatenation of $n$ copies of $\Sigma$. So I suppose your question should be reformulated as follows: "Is there a name for a language of the form $L_1 \dotsm L_n$, where each $L_i$ is a subset of $\Sigma$?"

Yeah you're right. I will do it.

I don't know of any established terminology, so you should coin your own one if needed. A possible suggestion would be a pack or a packet but you could prefer to call them Tetris languages in view of the following picture:
$\hskip 100pt$


If you are curious in the subject, I finally found a paper naming "degenerate strings" the language I described. For example, see https://drops.dagstuhl.de/storage/00lipics/lipics-vol113-wabi2018/LIPIcs.WABI.2018.21/LIPIcs.WABI.2018.21.pdf.

Thanks for the reference. Not sure I would follow this terminology if I had to, since a degenerate string is not a string but a set of strings, but apparently people use it, so you may have to adopt this term.
